# Illegal inheritance while extending trait with self type

Tags: scala

I'm confused by the following code:

```
    trait T1 {
        type S
    }

    trait T2 {
      self: T1 =>

       case  class ClS(s: S)
    }

    object O extends T2 {

    }
```

It gives out the following error message:

> illegal inheritance;  tests.O.type does not conform to tests.T2's
>   selftype tests.T2 with tests.T1

What's going wrong? the reason that I extend `O` with `T2` is that I want to reference the class `CLS` in `O`, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`trait T2` has a contract that says: If you inherit from me, you should also inherit from `T1`.

```
object O extends T2 with T1
```

You would then probably get an error that `type S` is not defined. Which is a good thing since it's used in the definition of `CLS`

Answer (score 6):

T2 has a self type T1, which means, that every class/object/trait inheriting from T2 has to be of type T1, so in your case

```
object O extens T1 with T2 {
  type S = Whatever
}
```

should work.