# Understanding TypeTag in Scala with Single Inheritence

Tags: scala

I came across this following piece of code which has a trait like this and has some methods defined in it:

```
    trait TypeTaggedTrait[Self] { self: Self =>

  /**
    * The representation of this class's type at a value level.
    *
    * Useful for regaining generic type information in runtime when it has been lost (e.g. in actor communication).
    */
  val selfTypeTag: TypeTag[Self]

  /**
    * Compare the given type to the type of this class
    *
    * Useful for regaining generic type information in runtime when it has been lost (e.g. in actor communication).
    *
    * @return true if the types match and false otherwise
    */
  def hasType[Other: TypeTag]: Boolean =
    typeOf[Other] =:= selfTypeTag.tpe

  /**
    * Attempt to cast this value to the given type.
    *
    * If the types match, the casted version is returned. Otherwise, empty value is returned.
    *
    * Useful for regaining generic type information in runtime when it has been lost (e.g. in actor communication).
    *
    * @return casted version wrapped in `Some` if the cast succeeds, and otherwise `None`
    */
  def cast[Other: TypeTag]: Option[Other] =
    if (hasType[Other])
      Some(this.asInstanceOf[Other])
    else
      None
}

abstract class TypeTagged[Self: TypeTag] extends TypeTaggedTrait[Self] { self: Self =>
  val selfTypeTag: TypeTag[Self] = typeTag[Self]
}
```

I then tried to implement this trait like this:

```
  case class MyCase(str: String, i: Int)

  final class MyTypeTagged[MyCase] extends TypeTagged[MyCase] {
    ....
    ....
  }
```

Obviously it fails compilation with the following message as seen in the screen shot.

[image]

Can anyone please help me with what is happening? If I give the whole MyTypeTagged[MyCase], it works. How should I interpret this? It is expecting the enclosing type as well. How should I interpret this?

Comment: As the TypeTaggedTrait has a [self-type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html) defined by its type parameter Self it can only be mixed in if the type argument (type value for Self) is the type that mixes in TypeTaggedTrait (Self = MyTypeTagged[MyCase]).

Comment: The question is slightly misleading/confusing since `TypeTag` in scala means something completely different.

Comment: I have edited my post now. Does that make sense?

Comment: Now it's clear where the `TypeTag` in the title comes from. However your compile error is not in any way related to `TypeTags`, as you may have noticed yourself since your minimization had no dependency on `TypeTag`.

Comment: So what is it then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal inheritance while extending trait with self type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951931/illegal-inheritance-while-extending-trait-with-self-type)

Comment: How come it is a duplicate of the other post which has multiple inheritence. In my case I just have a single trait

Comment: @sparkr, I think Jasper is right that this question is a duplicate. That question has an exact answer to why this code fails to compile. The only way to make this question not a duplicate I see is to describe your high-level problem that you are trying to solve with `MyTypeTagged` so we can suggest ways to implement it.